# Krita mysterious lines not on any layers

Tags: krita, bug

I was drawing in Krita and noticed a bunch of random lines near the top of the page, I tried to remove them however they don't seem to on any of the layers. As you can see on the image below all layers are invisible and yet the lines are still there.

[image]

How can I remove these lines?

Edit: The .kra file as requested, I removed the layers but the lines are still there.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gqcdd5q6sqbx6py/Krita%20Bugged.kra?dl=0

Edit 2: lines are still there on a copy I downloaded from dropbox.

[image: 2]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. It might be difficult to answer this question without access to the ,kra file. It might help if you were to share the file, perhaps using dropbox or some other file sharing service.

Comment: @BillyKerr I have added a stripped copy of the file using dropbox.

Comment: when I open the file I can't see these lines anywhere.

Comment: @BillyKerr Weird, there still there on my end and I haven't had this issue with any other Krita files. I guess I'll just have to hope it doesn't happen on any other files and try reinstalling Krita if it does.